# R creating a loop for multiple dataframes - Error: no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r, loops, group-by

I am struggling with creating simple loops in R. Does anyone have recommendations on readings?

I have 6 datasets with all the same columns and I would like to group each dataframe over columny and summarise the value in columnx. I used the code below:

```
dats = list(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6)

for (i in 1:length(dats)) {
names(dats[[i]]) = names(dats[[i]]) %>% group_by(columny) %>%
  summarize(columnx = sum(columnx, na.rm=TRUE))}
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

How can I create simple loops like this one in R?

Comment: `names(dats[[i]]` extract a single character that current df is named with. Drop the names argument in both left and right side.

Comment: Thanks JacobJacox, unfortunately if I drop the names argument, the function does nothing and the df does not get groupbyed and summarised..

Comment: I write an example in asnwers, since it is too big to post in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using loops it can make the logic harder to follow try mapping instead, thanks @JacobJacox for the fake dput

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100))
dats = list(df,df,df)

pipe <- . %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  summarise(colsum = sum(x,na.rm = TRUE))

dats %>% map(pipe)
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know this function, but now I can create more loops like this

Answer (score 1):

Try it something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100))
dats = list(df,df,df)

for (i in 1:length(dats)) {
  dats[[i]] = dats[[i]] %>% group_by(y) %>%
    summarize(columnx = sum(x, na.rm=TRUE))
}
dats[[1]]
# A tibble: 100 x 2
       y  columnx
   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 -2.78 -0.362  
 2 -2.02  0.1000 
 3 -1.79  0.802  
 4 -1.74  0.784  
 5 -1.65 -0.117  
 6 -1.60  1.41   
 7 -1.60 -0.0381 
 8 -1.48 -0.573  
 9 -1.47  0.00229
10 -1.26  0.522  
# ... with 90 more rows
```